# What is the scope of 'naming-convention' tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag [naming-convention](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naming-convention) has already been used for a variety of questions covering:

- geography place names
- suffixes
- inputting names into gen.software
- denoting adoptions
- language use
- historical vs. modern names
- culture-specific naming conventions (French)

I'm just wondering what the scope of this tag might be. Is it a catch-all for *anything to do with a name?* Does that mean that variations in spelling of family & given names would also be tagged thus?

In my own question [How do I research Chinese names that have been Americanized?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/69/how-do-i-research-chinese-names-that-have-been-americanized) I eschewed this tag and instead created the tag [chinese-names](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chinese-names), which I don't particularly like (and question whether it'll be used again in the next 6 months), even though Chinese names do present [particularly tricky problems](http://www.vpl.ca/ccg/Traditions.html). But then again, don't other cultures have their own name-related conundrums (for example the [French question](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/151/how-should-i-handle-french-canadian-dit-names-and-variant-spellings))? Swedish names, Scottish names, they all have peculiarities. - Yet, someone might choose to follow/subscribe to a tag called [scottish-names](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scottish-names), whereas they might not want to follow a "naming-convention" tag.

**Should chinese-names be deleted and everything just put under naming-convention?**

Comment: It might be worth while having both tags on your post. If in a month no one else used the chinese-names tag it might be worth while removing it at that point. But you never know, next week it might get used a lot one we move out of private.

Comment: @Justin808 good idea.

Comment: FWIW, unused/underused tags will be automatically deleted after some period of time (3 months?). It doesn't hurt to use extra tags and see what sticks and the patterns that eventually emerge as the site gets some real use.

Comment: It never hurts to have a well written tag wiki excerpt which clarifies what the tag should be used for.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to see a distinction between the tag naming-conventions and place-names. See the question here: [Is it proper to record the place name "United States of America" or "USA" as part of a historical event that pre-dates 1776?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/1662/is-it-proper-to-use-usa-in-a-location-prior-to-1776)